# Apache2 config to Nginx config?

Tags: apache, nginx

I have 2 ports running on my server right now.

1. that is the main application port 5455
2. socket port 8433

we are migrating this apache setup to Nginx.
In Apache, we had 2 conf files 1 for the application server and 1 for the socket

I have been able to move the application server correctly but not able to make the socket work

```
<VirtualHost _default_:8443>
    ServerAdmin admin@abc.tech
    ServerName api.abc.tech

    DocumentRoot /var/www/api.abc.tech/socket

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined



    SSLEngine on
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyVia Full

   <Proxy *>
      Require all granted
   </Proxy>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8000/$1 [P,L]

        ProxyPass /socket.io/ http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/
        ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ http://127.0.0.1:8000/socket.io/

  SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/sites-available/api.abc.tech.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/sites-available/api.abc.tech.key
  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
       SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
  nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
  downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

</VirtualHost>
```

My current Nginx file is as below

```
server {
    listen 8443;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8443;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.abc.tech/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.abc.tech/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name api.abc.tech;

    location / {

     proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
         proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
     proxy_pass         http://localhost:5455;

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 200;
            }
    }

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            allow all;
        }
}
```

so when the application hits the below route

```
https://api.abc.tech:8443/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MvOh2
```

it is returning below error

```
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

If you need any other information please feel free to ask

Any assistance on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You try to enter through https, and then downgrade to http with no certificate there. The server block of 8443 is in a constant proxy pass loop.